# Google Tag Manager: Selecting deeply nested a

Tags: google-tag-manager

I'm trying to capture all the anchor clicks.

In GTM, my trigger is:

```
 All Elements / Some Clicks / Click Element / Matches CSS Selector / #most-popular-posts > a
```

I've tried #most-popular-posts > * > a as well with no luck. Any ideas on why this isn't working?

My HTML is as follows:

```
 <div id="most-popular-posts">
    <h4>Most Popular</h4>
    <div class="post-loop">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a class="latest_thumbnail_wrapper" href="http://thelink.com">
                    <div class="latest_thumbnail">
                        <img src="https://theimage.jpg" class="attachment-loop-thumbnail size-loop-thumbnail wp-post-image" alt="">                         
                    </div>
                </a>
                <div class="latest_list_wrapper">
                    <h5 class="cat-label"><a href="https://cateogrylink.com">The Category</a></h5>
                    <h3>
                        <a href="hhttp://thelink.com">Article Title</a>
                    </h3>
                    <div class="byline">  
                        <span>by</span> <a class="author" href="">First Last Name</a></div>
                    </div>
                </li>
            <li>
        </ul>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `>` from the selector. That will look for any `<a>` tag inside of the `#most-popular-posts` element instead of looking for an `<a>` directly nested inside of that element.

See this Mozilla article for more details: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Introduction_to_CSS/Cascade_and_inheritance